# Suggested algorithms for time series analysis of sporadic events

Tags: time-series, frequency, randomness, fourier-transform

I have a series of sporadic, discrete time series events that appear to occur in shorter interval clusters and I am looking for a way to determine the frequencies at which the events occur. None of the fourier analysis packages seem to set up for these sparse events. I was thinking about some sort of logarithmic histogram to "bucketize" the time difference between events but am not sure what other options might be better. Any suggestions, or even better, java implementations would be much appreciated.